# Change image scale point

Tags: css

I have an image with a percentage max width.

```
img {
     max-width: 150%;
}
```

When I resize the browser window the image scales from the top left corner.

Is there a way to change the point from where the image scales?

E.g. this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dbVcy/

Is it possible to scale the image from the face of the woman, instead of the top left corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position to corners, such as the bottom right for example.

I updated your fiddle - here: http://jsfiddle.net/dbVcy/1/

Essentially, changed CSS to

```
img {
     max-width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

to get it from a point in the image you would have to manipulate the bottom and right (or top and left for example) with JQuery as you resize the browser - it should give it the illusion of being sized by the face in your case.

​